# Accuracy of adding float number to itself vs multiplication by 2

Tags: floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy

Multiplying a `float`/`double` by 2 should be exact as it just increases exponent part.

What about adding two floating numbers of same value? Will it be exact?

(If it matters, hardware is standard x86-64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic or any reasonable floating-point arithmetic, the result of *x* o *y*, where “o” is any operation, is the result you would get by performing *x* o *y* using real-number arithmetic and then rounding the real number result to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format as direct by the rounding rule in use for the operation. (Round-to-nearest-ties-to-even is the most common rule and the most common default, but there are other rules such as round upward [toward +∞], round downward, and round toward zero.) (This rule for determining the floating-point result applies to elementary operations. For hard-to-calculate functions, such as `pow`, correctly rounded results are not always provided.)

Therefore, the result that is obtained depends only on what the real-number result would be. In the calculation 2 • *x*, the real-number result would be 2*x*. In the calculation *x* + *x*, the real-number result would be 2*x*. Since these operations have the same real-number result, they will have the same floating-point result.

If the base of the floating-point format is two and we start with a number *x* representable in the format, then 2*x* is also representable unless it overflows the finite range of the format. If it does not overflow, the result is 2*x*, so the operation is exact.

If the floating-point format uses some other base, the result might not be exact. For example, with a three-digit decimal format, 7.89 is representable, but 2•7.89 = 15.78 is not representable, so the produced result, 15.8 will not be exact. However, it will be the same for 2•7.89 and 7.89+7.89. Even with bases that are powers of two, multiplying by two might not be exact. For example, with a three-digit octal format, 5.43<sub>8</sub> is representable, but 2•5.43<sub>8</sub> = 13.06<sub>8</sub> is not representable.